# textbox opening my link using if else statement javascript

Tags: javascript

i want excatly same thing but on else it will open link of my other .htm file. the whole code is fine but when i enter something in the textfeild i want a link to appear either in the alert or on the main window.

```
<script Language="JavaScript">
<!--
    function Blank_TextField_Validator() {
        // Check the value of the element named text_name from the form named text_form
        if (text_form.text_name.value == "") {
            // If null display and alert box
            alert("Please fill in the text field.");
            // Place the cursor on the field for revision
            text_form.text_name.focus();
            // return false to stop further processing
            return (false);
        }
        // If text_name is not null continue processing
        return (true);
    }
-->
</script>
<form name="text_form" method="get" action="#" onsubmit="return Blank_TextField_Validator()">
    <input type="text" name="text_name" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>​​​
```

Comment: Javaria. The question is not clearly understood. Please explain what you want to do exactly.

Comment: @javaria shah: Where is the link which needs to be shown?

Answer (score 0):

> but on else it will open link of my other .htm file.

"On else" you mean opening the link when the form submit returns true? If so, just put the link in the form's `action` attribute instead of `#`.

> but when i enter something in the textfeild i want a link to appear
>   either in the alert or on the main window.

If you want to display a message showing the link, put an `alert('www.example.com');` after your `// If text_name is not null continue processing`.

---

**EDIT**

I adapted your JS function:

```
<script Language="JavaScript">
<!--
function Blank_TextField_Validator() {
    // Check the value of the element named text_name from the form named text_form
    if (text_form.text_name.value == "") {
        // If null display and alert box
        alert("Please fill in the text field.");
        // Place the cursor on the field for revision
        text_form.text_name.focus();
        // return false to stop further processing
        return (false);
    }
    // If text_name is not null continue processing
    if (text_form.text_name.value == "project")
        window.open('project.htm');
    else if (text_form.text_name.value == "under")
        window.open('underconstruction.htm');
    else
        alert("Invalid keyword!");
    return (true);
}
-->
</script>
```

Comment: actually i have made a text box and i want to open my project.htm file when i enter project in the text field and press my submit button.
do it either in an alert meaage , by giving link in alret or displaying it on the main window.

Comment: form's `action` attribute usually sends the form's data to a php page when submitted, however, if you put a .html/.htm page in the `action` it'll simply open the page when you press submit. What do you mean with "open this link in alert"? Alert windows only show text strings, if you want to open the link in a new window try `window.open("http://www.example.com","_blank")` after the `// If text_name is not null continue processing`.

Comment: i have a textbox and a submit button, now i want to open my project.htm file and underconstruction.htm file. when i enter project keyword in textbox and press submit button project.htm should open and wheni enter under in textbox and press submit button underconstruction.htm link should open.

Comment: ok, give me a min and I'll update my answer to suit your comment.

Comment: my edited answer should do exactly what you want, it'll check if the keyword is valid and open the corresponding page in a new window. Just make sure that your 3 files are in the same folder.

Comment: is there a way in which i instead of opening the link in a new page , makes the link visible on the same page?

Comment: Yeah, just define the `target` as `_self` like this: `window.open("www.example.com", "_self");` You may also want to `return false` in both cases then, to prevent the page from submitting the form to itself instead of opening your link.